# buddyblog posts appears twice buddypress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am using buddypress. I have used `buddyblog` and `BP Simple Front End Post` to allow user to post blogs in frontend. The problem is all the posts are appearing two times in blog page only. How to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your site?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin author has just released a new version of the plugin which fixes the double post bug. See:

http://buddydev.com/buddypress/introducing-buddyblog-allow-users-to-blog-from-their-buddypress-profile/